# Replacing a thermistor sensor with a common resistor to 'trick' it

Tags: pcb, control, temperature, thermistor

Here's the catch: we have a device that has a sensor that helps shutting it down when air temperature is too high. This sensor is based on a thermistor.

We are now switching to a more powerful cooling method and wants this threshold gone. Since we can't alter the built-in control algorithms, can we uproot the thermistor from the pcb and replace it with a certain valued resistor to make the device think it's in a normal temperature?

Kind of a weird idea. Is it done before?

Comment: If it acts at thermal cut out, consider placing a resistor in series or parallel, depending in sensor type, in order to simply increase the level somewhat. Your warranty will be void by doing so though.

Comment: Pretty standard idea, I've done set ups with fixed resistors to check the ADC set up is working correctly for production tests. So it is easy to do: look up the temperature/reistance graph/formula in the datasheet and choose your value. But I would ask why you're bodging this. A thermal cut off is a saftey thing, if you don't have full access to the device, how can you be sure the device is going to be safe?

Comment: @Puffafish there are still cutoffs at the componenets in case they get hot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can be done easily:

1. Check the thermistor (typically possible through datasheets or a visual inspection).
2. Look up the resistance table for that thermistor (easily found on Google or similar). You'll find an ambient temperature and the resistance the thermistor provides at that temperature.
3. Acquire and install a resistor suitable to your goal in place of the thermistor.

If 1 is not possible, simply uninstall the thermistor, bring it to a desired ambient temperature and measure the resistance in place of steps 1 and 2. This will obviously prolong the downtime unless you have a great span of resistors handy.

**Do you need to?**
The way your question is phrased suggests this is not the appropriate solution. You mention the device shutting down because of too high ambient temperature and also mention that stronger cooling is being installed. In that case, surely the device wouldn't reach the threshold that causes it to shut down anyways?

**Note**
You did not specify the nature of the device. Some devices will expect changing values from sensors and will mark the sensor value as "stale" if it remains unchanged for a defined period of time.

If you know or suspect this to be the case, you can instead add a resistor in series (typically) or parallel to the thermistor instead of replacing it entirely. This will create a varying value that is simply offset from the actual ambient temperature.

Also note that if the device is very critical, the manufactors may have opted to install two or even several sensors to average or compare their values.

Answer (score 0):

> We are now switching to a more powerful cooling method and wants this threshold gone.

If you cool it better, then it will not reach the temperature threshold, right? So what exactly is the problem? The thermistor was there to detect when the cooling was insufficient ant the enclosure (presumably) got too hot. You cool it better, no problem...

Comment: if we cool it better (higher HTC), the componenets can run with a higher ambient temperature, so we want a more tolerating threshold.